# Jython gives "Cannot create PyString with non-byte value" error

Tags: java, python, jython, illegalargumentexception, jython-2.7

my code:

```
from javax.swing import JFrame

frame = JFrame("Hello")
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
frame.setLocation(100,100)
frame.setSize(300,200)
frame.setVisible(True)
```

But I can't open jython in cmd it gives this error, idk why it is. When I made same thing in java with jython(eclipse) its working.

```
C:\>jython banana.py
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.python.core.PySystemState.<clinit>(PySystemState.java:73)
        at org.python.util.jython.main(jython.java:533)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PyString with non-byte value
        at org.python.core.PyString.<init>(PyString.java:57)
        at org.python.core.PyString.<init>(PyString.java:70)
        at org.python.core.PyString.<init>(PyString.java:74)
        at org.python.core.Py.newString(Py.java:643)
        at org.python.core.PyJavaType.init(PyJavaType.java:543)
        at org.python.core.PyType$Registry.createType(PyType.java:477)
        at org.python.core.PyType$Registry.addFromClass(PyType.java:426)
        at org.python.core.PyType$Registry.resolveType(PyType.java:352)
        at org.python.core.PyType$Registry$1.computeValue(PyType.java:208)
        at org.python.core.PyType$Registry$1.computeValue(PyType.java:202)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.getFromHashMap(ClassValue.java:226)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.getFromBackup(ClassValue.java:208)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.get(ClassValue.java:114)
        at org.python.core.PyType.fromClass(PyType.java:2137)
        at org.python.core.PyObject.<init>(PyObject.java:85)
        at org.python.core.PySingleton.<init>(PySingleton.java:9)
        at org.python.core.PyNotImplemented.<init>(PyNotImplemented.java:10)
        at org.python.core.Py.<clinit>(Py.java:66)
        ... 2 more
```

but `jython --version` working well, jython gives the same error output. Im stuck

Comment: Is that all your code?

Comment: yes. its all of my code

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem with the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with some Windows 10 Pro instances (see: https://bugs.jython.org/issue2890).

As for the solution, you may try to attach a debugger OR add the following println to PyJavaType.java in order to print out the reflected classes:

```
    // Fill in the __module__ attribute of PyReflectedFunctions.
    if (reflectedFuncs.size() > 0) {
        if (nameSpecified == null) {
            System.out.println(name);
            nameSpecified = Py.newString(name);
            
        }
        for (PyReflectedFunction func : reflectedFuncs) {
            func.__module__ = nameSpecified;
        }
    }
```

Sample output:

```
C:\java -jar jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar
reflectedconstructor
reflectedfield
reflectedfunction
beanproperty
java.lang.Object
java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement
java.lang.reflect.GenericDeclaration
java.lang.reflect.Type
java.lang.Class
singleton
notimplemented
javapackage
org.python.core.JavaImporter
.
.
.
```

I suspect it's something to do with the "notimplemented" class (from the stack trace).  I have not been able to reproduce on Win 10 Pro.